# method called by javascript interface wont update view

Tags: android

Been stuck on this for a while now.  I have a webviewfragment that has a html file, that i created, loaded.  In the html file is some javascript that will allow me to call some methods in my android application.  Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="Guideline1.gif" usemap="#Guideline9" border="0" />
<map name="Guideline9" id="generalGuideline9">
 <area shape="rect" coords="124,329,290,357" onClick="Android.TestMethod();" />
</map>


</body>
</html>
```

The WebViewFragment code looks like this:

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
public class MyWebView extends WebViewFragment {

android.webkit.WebView wv;
String name2;
String fileName2;
String itemFileName;

CommunicateWithMyWebView mCallback;

public interface CommunicateWithMyWebView {
    public void toggleActionBar();
    public void addTab();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
     mCallback = (CommunicateWithMyWebView) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement CommunicateWithMyWebView");
    }

}



@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    name2=getArguments().getString("name2"); 
    fileName2=getArguments().getString("fileName2");
    itemFileName = "file:///android_asset/" + fileName2 + ".html";

    wv = getWebView();

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this.getActivity()), "Android"); 

    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    wv.setLongClickable(true);

    wv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            mCallback.toggleActionBar();
            return false;
        }
    });

    wv.loadUrl(itemFileName);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Activity mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Activity activity) {
        mContext = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void TestMethod() {


        mCallback.addTab();
    }
}
```

}

This gets me to the point of having my webviewfragment calling a method of the parent activity, which is working.  The MainActivity implements the CommunicateWithMyWebView interface.  Here is the portion of the main activity code that has the addTab() method:

```
public void addTab() {

    tabsFrag.test1();

}
```

tabsFrag is another fragment being displayed by the MainActivity. Here is the code for the test1() function in the tabsFrag:

```
public void test1() {

    Log.d("MyApp", "" + b1.getText());
}
```

b1 is a button inside of the tabs frag.  This code works fine as I have shown it.  But if I change the log command to :

```
public void test1() {

    b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Given that b1's visibility was currently VISIBLE, it won't change the visibility on the emulator (but won't crash, API 18), but will stall and crash on the tablet i have to test on . A samsung galaxy tab running 4.0.4.

If i call the test1() method in tabsFrag from any other method, so long as the action wasnt originating from the map area click in the html file, setting the visibility works fine with no crashes or anything.

I'm not really sure how to implement try catch blocks here.

any help i could get would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ui thread to change the view state.

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void TestMethod() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

              mCallback.addTab();
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: thank you.  I just found that late last night.  It works.  I will accept your answer.